# MySQL: Assigning column name / handle to a subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm using MySQL to develop a blog site. I'm running a subquery that runs across two tables.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `blog_entries`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_entries` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    `live` boolean default FALSE,
    `date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `author` int(3) default 0,
    `body` text NOT NULL,
    `category` int(2) default 0,
    `tags` varchar(255) default '',
    UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `blog_entry_comments`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `blog_entry_comments` (
    `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    `blog_entry_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
    `live` boolean default FALSE,
    `date` datetime NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(128) default '',
    `email` varchar(128)    default '',
    `web` varchar(128)  default '',
    `comments` text NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The query looks like this:

```
SELECT be.id, be.title, 
       (SELECT (COUNT(bec.blog_entry_id)) AS blog_entry_comments_total 
        FROM blog_entry_comments bec 
        WHERE be.id = bec.blog_entry_id), 
       (SELECT (COUNT(bec.blog_entry_id)) AS blog_entry_comments_disabled 
        FROM blog_entry_comments bec 
        WHERE be.id = bec.blog_entry_id AND bec.live = 0) 
FROM blog_entries be;
```

Now I thought that the bit that says 'AS blog_entry_comments_total' and 'AS blog_entry_comments_disabled' would name the result columns into those respective names but as you can see from the results of what I get below I got the whole subquery as the column name:

```
| id | title | (SELECT (COUNT(bec.blog_entry_id)) AS blog_entry_comments_total FROM blog_entry_comments bec WHERE be.id = bec.blog_entry_id) | (SELECT (COUNT(bec.blog_entry_id)) AS blog_entry_comments_disabled FROM blog_entry_comments bec WHERE be.id = bec.blog_entry_id AND bec.live = 0) |

+----+----------------

|  1 | Blog Entry One | 3 | 1
|  2 | New Post | 0 | 0
|  3 | Testing | 0 | 0

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

What I need is a handle that I can use to reference this column and this doesn't seem to provide a reasonably named handle. What I am looking for is a result set that looks something like this:

```
| id | title | blog_entry_comments_total | blog_entry_comments_disabled |

+----+----------------

|  1 | Blog Entry One | 3 | 1
|  2 | New Post | 0 | 0
|  3 | Testing | 0 | 0

3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the alias in the wrong place.  It should look like this:

```
SELECT be.id, be.title, 
       (SELECT (COUNT(bec.blog_entry_id))
        FROM blog_entry_comments bec 
        WHERE be.id = bec.blog_entry_id) AS blog_entry_comments_total, 
       (SELECT (COUNT(bec.blog_entry_id)) 
        FROM blog_entry_comments bec 
        WHERE be.id = bec.blog_entry_id AND bec.live = 0) AS blog_entry_comments_disabled

FROM blog_entries be;
```

Comment: oh thank you so much! couldn't find that answer anywhere. that's spot on!